# Inverse Int Order in scalaz.Heap

Tags: scala, implicit, scalaz

I'm using [scalaz.Heap](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.1.1/scalaz_2.11-7.1.1-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.Heap) in problem where i need to extract maximum values instead of minimum.

What i've tried so far:

1. Using negated integers - **ugly, unhandy**
2. Declaring `implicit val reversedOrder: Order[Int] = Order[Int].reverseOrder` in scope - **did not work**
3. Using such construction imitating haskell's `newtype`:

   ```
   implicit class Inverse[T](val restore:T)(implicit order: Order[T])

   implicit def inverseOrder[T](implicit ord:Order[T]):Order[Inverse[T]] = new Order[Inverse[T]]{
       override def order(x: Inverse[T], y: Inverse[T]): Ordering = ord.order(y.restore,x.restore)
       override def equal(x: Inverse[T], y: Inverse[T]): Boolean = ord.equal(x.restore, y.restore)
       override def equalIsNatural: Boolean = ord.equalIsNatural
   }
   ```

   **too heavy**
4. Passing implicits directly - means not only additional parameter for each call, but also additional instance for `Foldable[List]` to my Heap constructor and using `insert` instead of `+` - **way too heavy**

How one could convince scala compiler to use your own `implicit val` instead of provided, or how should this task could be completed properly?

**UPD**:
One option i described in self-answer, but is there a possibility to just specify more preffered implicit for some scope in scala?

Comment: You can pass implicit parameters explicitly if you need to.

Comment: @Lee, yes i forgotten this as another heavy thing i tried

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solution is not import default instance.

So i replaced `import Scalaz._` with `import Scalaz.{..only needed instances..}`
And changed my instance defitinition to
`implicit val reversedOrder: Order[Int] = Scalaz.intInstance.reverseOrder`

Comment: This can get you into trouble fast (like the first time you or someone else uses `insert` in a context with the default instance). Using a newtype-style wrapper is probably better, and isn't as bad as the question suggests.